# How to install JRE 8.0 on eclips

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to install jre 8.0 on eclipse neon, when I go preferences>java>Installed JRE's>add>standardVM I don't know what it is asking for when it requires a JRE home, it needs a specific type of directory and I don't know what that is.  I tried downloading the JRE from elipse's website, but when I put that in it doesn't work.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse Neon has a dependency on Java8. And atleast JRE needs to be installed. However for most development efforts a JDK environment is recommended. You want to download and install Jdk8 or JRE8 from Oracle site and setup the Java_Home and Path environment variables in Advanced System Settings.

Test that you have java installed correctly by running java -version on the command prompt.

If done correctly, eclipse will automatically detect your jre.

If the project needs the jre to be identified under Preferences as you were trying, you need to check where jre is installed on your machine. Normally it is either "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-version_no" or "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-version_no\jre". Browse the location, give it a unique name (if it automatically doesnt detect) and it should let you add it.

Answer (score 0):

download and install Jdk8 or JRE8 from Oracle site and setup the Path in environment variables then test it using command prompt, if it's working properly then ur good to go. Go to add external jar and u will find it as system jars, if u have multiple jdk versions then it will show u all the list, u just add the version u like ( I guess jre8). It's very simple steps, ask me if it doesn't work out. I can help u in remote installation also